# SharePoint Calculated Column - Get Dynamic Column ID

Tags: sharepoint

I have a number column called "Team Leader", "Process Lead", "Regional Manager"

I will get Team Leader Name, if "Team Leader" Column is Blank, then Get the Name of "Process Lead", if Both Column is Blank then Get the Name of "Regional Manager"

I also have a calculated column that looks to this column.

=IF(ISBLANK([Team Leader]),"",[Team Leader]),=IF(ISBLANK(["Process Lead]),"",[Process Lead])

This is where I am with my formula which doesn't work.  Has anyone achieved this?
﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these 2 should help you:

First, result in blank value if Regional Manager is not provided.

```
IF(ISBLANK([Test column1]),IF(ISBLANK([Test Column2]),IF(ISBLANK([Test Column3]),"",[Test Column3]),[Test Column2]),[Test column1])
```

Another one:

```
IF(ISBLANK([Test column1]),IF(ISBLANK([Test Column2]),IF(ISBLANK([Test Column3]),"",[Test Column3]),[Test Column2]),[Test column1])
```

[image]

Comment: Really sorry to say that, both Formula are not getting a result, even am getting an error

The exact Column Name is below 

Process Lead / Sr. SME
Team Leader
Region Manager


"The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column"

Comment: Am looking answer for this request

Comment: Updated the answer with a screen shot, which shows the formula is working as expected, you just have to put the correct column names.